# How to pass custom certificate in openssl command line

Tags: ssl, openssl, libcurl

I'm new to "openssl", I had been working with libcurl before. Since we are facing an issue with the connectivity I was asked to check how the ssl connection is happening if we try from the command line.

I'm able to get information about connecting to a server.

Since the connection is a secure one it needs some custom certificate to be added when I try to create the connection.

Can someone tell me how to pass a custom certificate (where I can store them for openssl to use?) during the connection?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Which command do you currently use? `s_client`?

Comment: openssl s_client -connect <domain name:port>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about a custom CA cert or a client cert?

You provide ca cert to s_client's -CApath or -CAfile options, or if you're talking about a client cert you want -cert (and friends).

See [s_client's man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html).